# MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to 52.206.125.240:27017 closed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mern

Im trying to save a registration in mongodb through post method on mongodb atlas. Im using mern stack (mongoose framework). I provided correct connection string and correct password, but it keeps giving me an error.. please help u.u

Answer (score 4):

it's solved. but if you re here because you have the same problem:

go to mongodb atlas and check on NETWORK ACCESS what IP is added. In case you needed remove all and add the current you have (I did that and it works)

good luckk

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I created the cluster yesterday and wanted to test it today and totally forgot that i need to change the ip again...